# How do I pass Authentication Method Reference from Azure/Entra ID to AWS Identity Center

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, multi-factor-authentication

I am using Azure/Entra ID as the IDP for my AWS account and federating via AWS Identity Center.
I would like to pass the ‘Authentication Method Reference’ from Azure to Identity Center as a Session tag to be able to use MFA status to protect resources in AWS.

Azure allows passing Claim tokens in the SAML token but I don’t see these in the session. Also, there doesn’t seem to be any mechanism for passing the authnmethodsreferences attribute as a session tag / claim in the SAML token.

Any suggestions ?